# What happens to products created under distriqt vibration license after the license expires?

Tags: vibration, distriqt

The license for the vibration ANE is good for one year (renewable). Will the ANE in products created during that year stop working after the license expires? (I assume that if I need to update the program after one year, I would have to purchase the license again.)

Answer (score 0):

The subscription is for support and access to updates only. If it expires your license allows you to use the current version indefinitely and nothing will happen to any running applications. You will no longer have access to the extension updates however.

Best to contact us directly or in github for questions like this rather than using SO as it's not really a development question.